# Compare multiple Image Histograms with Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing

[picture histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ1mi.png)

I'm quite new to the processing language. I am trying to create an image comparison tool.

The idea is to get a histogram of a picture (see screenshot below, size is 600x400), which is then compared to 10 other histograms of similar pictures (all size 600x400). The histogram shows the frequency distribution of the gray levels with the number of pure black values displayed on the left and number of pure white values on the right.

In the end I should get a "winning" picture (the one that has the most similar histogram).

Below you can see the code for the image histogram, similar to the processing tutorial example.

My idea was to create a `PImage []` for the 10 other pictures to create histograms and then an if statement, but I'm not sure how to code it.

Does anyone have a tip on how to proceed or where to look? I couldn't find a similar post.

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is very basic!

```
  size(600, 400);

    // Load an image from the data directory
    // Load a different image by modifying the comments

PImage img = loadImage("image4.jpg");
    image(img, 0, 0);
    int[] hist = new int[256];

    // Calculate the histogram

for (int i = 0; i < img.width; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < img.height; j++) {
        int bright = int(brightness(get(i, j)));
        hist[bright]++; 
      }
 }

    // Find the largest value in the histogram
    int histMax = max(hist);

    stroke(255);
    // Draw half of the histogram (skip every second value)

for (int i = 0; i < img.width; i += 2) {
      // Map i (from 0..img.width) to a location in the histogram (0..255)

int which = int(map(i, 0, img.width, 0, 255));
      // Convert the histogram value to a location between 
      // the bottom and the top of the picture

int y = int(map(hist[which], 0, histMax, img.height, 0));
      line(i, img.height, i, y);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your problem is the implementation in processing or if you don't know how to compare histograms. I assume it is the comparison as the rest is pretty straight forward. Calculate the similarity for every candidate and pick the winner.

Search the web for histogram comparison and among others you will find:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html

OpenCV implements four measures for histogram similarity.

> Correlation
>
> [image]
>
> where [image] and N is the number of histogram bins

or

> Chi-Square
>
> [image]

or

> Intersection
>
> [image]

or

> Bhattacharyya-Distance
>
> [image]

You can use these measures, but I'm sure you'll find something else as well.

Comment: @julia_3010 please accept the answer so everyone knows no further answers are necessary, if this is the case.